# Google Maps API 3 - geocode is not working right

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my current code (i feel the problem is in my `codeAddress` function):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>`
<script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 320px;" ></div>
<div id="address">92867</div>
```

What I want to do is when the page loads, the address will be populated via PHP. I want the codeAddress to run with the populated address. How can I tweak this script to replace this `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);` with the correct code for my specified address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove

   ```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);
   ```

   and add this:

   ```
   codeAddress()
   ```

   to the end of `initialize()` , to ensure that the map has been created when `codeAddress();` will be executed
2. replace this line:

   ```
   var address = document.getElementById("address").text;
   ```

   by that line:

   ```
   var address = document.getElementById("address").firstChild.data;
   ```

   There is no text-property for a <div/>